# MyBatis - LazyLoading only overridable at assocation but not collection?

Tags: java, lazy-loading, mybatis

I've got some MyBatis code here (pretty straight forward) and enabled lazyLoading globally...

```
    <setting name="lazyLoadingEnabled" value="true" />
```

Now I want to disable lazy loading for one specific collection (since the lazyLoading creates Proxy objects that interfere with my code), for example...

```
    <collection column="ID" property="contractObjects" select="CONTRACTOBJECT.XML_MAP.findContractObject"/>
```

Unfortunately, it seems that a fetchType="eager" is only possible at an `assocation`, but not a `collection`.

So, is there any way to disable lazyLoading for one specific `collection`, but not globally?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, simple version problem, a more current version (3.3.0) seems to allow fetchType for collections.